# shell library for Debian package releases

Tags: bash

This is a `bash` library intended to be used in a CI/CD pipeline to make finding the next release number for a Debian package semi-automatic.  I figured out how to use a JSON file as a metadata store since the CI/CD pipeline I'm working with doesn't provide any metadata storage across jobs.

I'm basically happy with how this is working.  We've used it for a few weeks without finding any bugs yet.  I'm happy that it passes [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/), but I'd also like to have some linting for ensuring that the code is documented adequately.  I'm not sure if my use of `jq` makes this too hard to maintain or if it just that using `jq` like this is so new to me.

## deblib.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# TODO: generate $PKGJSON from Debian repo metadata
PKGJSON=/opt/org_foo/var/packaging/packaging.json

# deb-release-number
# ------------------
#
# Arguments:
# 1. (required) package name
# 2. (required) package version ("upstream" version)
# 3. (optional) architecture (defaults to amd64)
# 4. (optional) packager (defaults to 1org_foo)
#
# Testing:
# Test by running
#       bash deblib.sh debug
# or passing any argumenet in to activate the "verification" section below

function deb-release-number {
        # read arguments
        PKGNAME=${1?provide package name as first argument}
        PKGVER=${2?provide package version as second argument}
        PKGARCH=${3:-amd64}
        PACKAGER=${4-1org_foo}

        # find latest release of this package/version
        RELEASE=$(jq -r ".\"latest_version\".\"${PKGNAME}\".\"${PKGVER}\"" <"$PKGJSON" )
        if [[ "$RELEASE" == "null" ]];
        then
                # start at 0 so the first release ends up being 1 after the increment below
                RELEASE=0
        fi
        ## echo RELEASE=$RELEASE

        # increment
        RELEASE=$(( RELEASE + 1 ))
        LONGPKGVER="${PKGVER}-${PACKAGER}-${RELEASE}" # seperated with dashes
        PKGFILENAME="${PKGNAME}_${LONGPKGVER}_${PKGARCH}.deb" # seperated with underscores
        echo "new release $RELEASE of $PKGNAME creates filename $PKGFILENAME"

        # backup
        cp "$PKGJSON" "${PKGJSON}.bak"

        # update release_version (into tmp file)
        jq ".\"latest_version\".\"${PKGNAME}\".\"${PKGVER}\" = \"${RELEASE}\"" <"$PKGJSON" >"${PKGJSON}.tmp"
        ## grep "$PKGVER" "${PKGJSON}.tmp"

        # update built_packages (out of tmp file into main file)
        jq ".\"built_packages\" += [\"${PKGFILENAME}\"]" <"${PKGJSON}.tmp" >"$PKGJSON"
        ## grep "$PKGNAME" "$PKGJSON"

        return $RELEASE
}

# verification
if [[ $# -gt 0 ]];
then
        deb-release-number librdkafka1 1.0.0
        deb-release-number foo 1.1.0 noarch
fi
```

## Example

An example of usage:

```
source deblib.sh
deb-release-number 'foo-stuff' "${GIT_TAG#v}" 'amd64'
PKGRELEASE=$?
```

Answer (score 2):

Some lints:

- Uppercase names are by convention only for `export`ed variables.
- You can use `getopt` to parse parameters. This should make it easier to handle optional parameters, and also makes it easy to avoid positional parameters (which makes commands more self-documenting).
- [Use More Quotes™](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)
- I would guard against errors and accidents by using `set -o errexit -o noclobber -o nounset -o pipefail` at the top of the script.
- `return`ing anything other than an *exit code* is a problem. You function should instead *output* the value (and ensure other output goes to standard error). One issue is the semantics of conflating exit codes. The other is the lingering bug because exit codes *wrap around* after 255.
- You can use `mktemp --directory` to create a temporary directory to store intermediate results. Even better would be to pass results in a pipeline to avoid any temporary files.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'm ok with the limit of 255 on exit values for this use case, but I probably should add some error checking for that.  Turning it into something that returns by output would mess with the other stuff printed out in there.

Comment: Shellcheck strongly encourages quoting to avoid problems so I thought I was doing pretty well there.  Is there some line that bothers you in my code or would you prefer to see almost everything quoted?

Comment: returning by output has other problems too, like it's slow, and you can't error exit because the function is running inside `$( )` and will only exit the subshell, not the script.   A useful idiom is returning via variable name taken as an argument, as in `printf -v$3 %d $RELEASE`